# Receiving this error. No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'presentViewController'

Tags: selector, viewcontroller, visible

The problem is at the if `([[topViewController presentViewController]` line:

```
(void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            UIViewController *topViewController =
            self.navController topViewController];

            if ([[topViewController presentViewController]
                 isKindOfClass:[PBLoginViewController class]]) {
                [topViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: There is no method "presentViewController".  It's presentViewController:animated:completion:

Comment: Or "presentingViewController".  Or "presentedViewController".